# NSLineBreakByWordWrapping on First Line but NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail For Second Line?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel, word-wrap

Is this possible?

I want to have a two line label. On the first line, I want it to wrap on words. But for the second line, if the text is too long, I want it to truncate by tail and add the ellipses `"..."` after.

Any ideas on the simplest way to do this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does this automatically if you use NSLineBreakByWordWrapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my comment I was wrong about the line break mode. If you just drag out a UILabel, the default line break is Truncate Tail, which is what you want. If you make the label twice as high, and set the lines to 2, the text will wrap, and if too long for the second line, it will show the ellipsis. No need to do anything fancy.

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes you have those dumb moments when you overlook the easiest solution. Setting numberOfLines = 2 worked for exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `setTruncatesLastVisibleLine:YES` property on `UITextField`?

I know this is only on `UITextField` **but** if you remove any border (and disable editing) it looks just like a UILabel, and you will get the functionality you desire.

```
textField.enabled = NO;
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
```

Comment: UILabel has no such property.

Comment: No problem, I corrected to note that it's really a UITextField and gave some more example code.