# iOS - Combine NSLineBreakByWordWrapping and NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

**What I need**

I need to write some text to a PDF. The text itself can be any length, but I can only display 2 lines (by word wrapping) and should truncate the tail in the second line if the space isn't enough.

**What I've tried**

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *text = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
text.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

This way, the text goes only in the first line, and truncates at the end of the line.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *text = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
text.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

This way, the text wraps to the second line, but if there's enough text for more lines, there's no truncating at the end of the second line.

I need some way to combine these two behaviours.

**What I've researched**

I've found some questions about problems with word wrapping, but nothing like this.
The nearest I've got was this:

[NSLineBreakByWordWrapping on First Line but NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail For Second Line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536260/nslinebreakbywordwrapping-on-first-line-but-nslinebreakbytruncatingtail-for-seco)

But the problem there was different. In that question, the asker wants this behaviour but in a label, and he fixes the problem with some storyboard configuration that I've also used in other part of my project. But this question is about this behaviour in a PDF, using the `NSStringDrawingContext` `drawInRect` method.

I'm using iOS 7 (actually just updated to 7.1, but the situation is the same in both).

Thanks in advance.

Edit - also, I've looked this link before asking, but with no help:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSLineBreakByWordWrapping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to :

```
@interface NSAttributedString (NSExtendedStringDrawing)
- (void)drawWithRect:(CGRect)rect options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
@end
```

Pass "NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine" for options, please note this method is only available for NSAttributedString.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the reply. I didn't have time to try your answer earlier, but now I'm checking it and I didn't get it right. I was using: 
`- (void)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect withAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attrs NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);`
but in your example, I don't know what to pass in the context parameter, since I don't use this NSStringDrawingContext in my class. Any hint?

Comment: You can pass a default context via [NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init].

Comment: I'm sorry by not accepting your answer, but little after asking the question the whole project got out of my hands and I've never been able to actually try your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you! It works as expected.The NSAttributedString is drawn on multiple lines and the last line is truncated correctly with "…" at the end.

Comment: @Tomusm Since you've tested and says it works, I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Answer in Swift 4,

```
let str = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "long string")
str.draw(with: label.frame, options: [NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .truncatesLastVisibleLine], context: nil)         
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.attributedText = str.copy() as? NSAttributedString
```