# How to combine NSLineBreakByCharWrapping and NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail?

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I need to combine NSLineBreakByCharWrapping and NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail .

Here is the condition, a UILabel's content is of multiple lines . There is a number id in the middle of the string , like "...You buyed some coco, Id is 12345678901234567890 , enjoy it...", If I use NSLineBreakByWordWrapping, the number id will fill a line. Not very good .

I have read [iOS - Combine NSLineBreakByWordWrapping and NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396347/ios-combine-nslinebreakbywordwrapping-and-nslinebreakbytruncatingtail), not fit.

Calculate the size , and replace some last words with `...` . The sentance's length is various , I did not get a accurate formula.

So how to combine NSLineBreakByCharWrapping and NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail?

Comment: Basically you want to show the full string in multiple lines. And the id is being ... while showing. Right?

Comment: I want to show the full string in multiple lines . And the id is NSLineBreakByCharWrapping. The end of the string is truncatesLastVisibleLine. The end is '...' , the id is not '...'

Comment: Ok
So, You need to calculate the height of the text for the UILabel.
Please try using `sizeCount` method from https://github.com/kumarpramod017/Extensions/blob/master/StringExtension.swift 
this extension of the `String`
Font: Pass the font of the UILabel.
boundignSize: Pass the Width of the UILabel and height about 10000, because you need to calculate the height of the UILabel.
And let me know if you get stuck to achieve this.

Comment: This will likely require custom logic where you calculate the size of a string will removing the last character iteratively until the size is within the bounds of your text field; then append a "..." and keep removing the letters before the "..." until that fits as well; all while using wordWrapping the whole time.

Comment: Yeah , I saw the solution in S.O. It works in theory. While working with different iPhone sizes, there is usually some empty space in the end , before '...' .  @Albert Renshaw